# std::sort of vector of lowercase strings appears to be comparing against an empty string

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  std::vector<std::string> lst{"cat", "dog", "dogs", "chicken", "chickens", "cats", "dogs"};
  std::sort(lst.begin(), lst.end(), [](const auto &lhs, const auto &rhs)
  {
    int i = 0;
    int n = lhs.size();
    int m = rhs.size();
    // cout << "a" << endl;
    std::cout << n << " " << m << std::endl;

    while(i < n && i < m && lhs.at(i) == rhs.at(i))
    {
      ++i;
    }


    if(i == n && i == m) return true; // same exact word
    else if(i == n || i == m) return lhs.size() < rhs.size(); 

    return lhs.at(i) < rhs.at(i);
  });
  // sort(lst.begin(), lst.end());

  // for(const auto &s : lst) cout << s << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to sort a list of lowercase strings, and I'm confused what's going on here. When I print the size of the `lhs` and `rhs` strings, they're sometimes zero. Why is the `sort` function comparing an input string against an empty string even those the empty string is not in the list of strings I'm trying to sort?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] please? Also, please include the actual output, not just your summary thereof. That said, the predicate is not supposed to return true for two equally sorting elements, just so you know.

Comment: Perhaps this comparison is part of the sorting algorithm. Does it sort the vector correctly?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I thought I did that with the example in the OP? I don't know how much more minimal it can get beyeond that.

Comment: @WaisKamal No it does not. I think there may be something wrong with my lambda.

Comment: This is not a [mre].  It's perhaps _minimal_, but [it's not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/r6ne5Yfs4).

Comment: It's not complete, @user5965026. I can't compile and run it to get the output you're seeing (which is still missing). Think about it, the error could be in the code you don't show or it could be that the code is not similar enough to even cause the unwanted effect.

Comment: even make it run, it still doesn't show what you describe https://wandbox.org/permlink/kpOVBSAK1XEnaiR4

Comment: what are you getting and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: @appleapple Hmm I'm seeing the zeros on my end. I just copy and pasted the full compilable code.

Comment: Why not just `std::sort(lst.begin(), lst.end())`? It seems that you're trying to do a lexicographical comparison, which you'd get by just omitting the lambda.

Comment: @Justin I just wanted to try writing the comparison myself to see if I understood how it works and apparently I don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `if(i == n && i == m) return true; // same exact word`

That's not a valid strict weak ordering.

Comment: Why? Isn't it just saying to put `lhs` before `rhs`?

Comment: @user5965026 and if you swap those parameters, it also says to put `rhs` before `lhs`.

Comment: For a predicate `p` and an element `a`, the call `p(a, a)` should never return `true`.

Comment: A value cannot be less than itself. Both `a<b` and `b<a` cannot be true, even if `b == a`. You need to return `false` if they're equal.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That's obviously false. E.g. if the predicate expects semantics of "less than or equal to", then `p(a, a)` should absolutely return true. What you say is correct when `p` is supposed to model the semantics of a "less than", or any other non-reflexive relation.

Comment: @Justin `std::sort` requires a less than type of relationship, not less then or equal to.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, but Ulrich said, "predicate", which is any function that returns a boolean. `std::sort` expects the predicate to model a "less than" relationship.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ah I see. Is there a fix for this situatiom with duplicate strings?

Comment: @user5965026 Return `false` when things are equal, because if they are equal then neither is less then the other.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh I understand now. The strict weakness is only true if it's (as the same suggests) strict smaller than the right hand side, and false otherwise. But why would what I had cause comparisons against (seemingly) empty strings?

Comment: @user5965026 Because you have undefined behavior if you don't.  `std::sort` is going to eventually try to compare `dogs` (index 2) with `dogs` (index 6) and that is going to compare true, when it shouldn't,, and that is going to violate the strict weak ordering requirement.  Once you do that, you've broken the function and all results are "valid"